# Automatically write setters already generated for a specific class

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not asking how to generate getters and setters. Read.

It's not uncommon that I've an entity where I need to do something like this :

```
myEntity.setName(name);
myEntity.setFirstName(firstname);
myEntity.setDog(dog);
myEntity.setHouse(house);
myEntity.setBoat(boat);
myEntity.setHairs(hair);
```

And I find it a bit annoying that I've to write the first one, then the second one , then if I have 10 of them I've to double check I did all of those. ( I find this clearer to read than a constructor).

Is there a shortcut make all the setters ( that are already written in a class ) appear where my cursor is? Then I can delete the ones I don't need for each situation. I'm not talking about generating getters and setters (source generate getters and setters). Or even better I'd hit a shortcut say ctrl+? then a table would appear with all the setters and I can enter everything I need and the setters would appear where my cursor is. I'm kinda asking for much yeah I was just wondering if that feature existed. If not it's no biggie.

Comment: If you are just creating the object, use the constructor. Else, why not define a method to receive all at once?

Comment: @FirstOne Of course I can do that, but I wanted to know if there was something built-in. That would just make things easier. It's not game changing, I was just thinking while writing code "hey maybe this functionality exist, that'd be neat. Let's ask.". Beside I find this easier to read than a function with parametters, especially if you have lots of them.

Comment: If you find yourself writing classes which have many setters, you might want to check out the Builder Pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).  This allows you to construct your objects on the same line, and it would allow your IDE to auto-hint your object's setter methods while you are creating it.

Comment: So basically you want something like [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/userinterface/property_pane.html?cp=67_3_2_1) for non-visual components. Maybe there is a trick to use it without gui related stuff, but I don’t know such a trick. Still, it is capable of generating the setter calls, thus the closest to your wish so far.

Comment: @Holger yeah exactly. But when I finish with the GUI and press ok, it would write the code at the position of my cursor, like in my example above entity.setName(name) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method chaining might be useful here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

But no there is no easy way around this.

Comment: No problemo. You are the only one who actually answered it :p I just wanted to know if that feature existed and apparently it doesn't so.. Good answer. Here, have 10 more.

Answer (score 0):

May be invert it? `dog.setOwner(myEntity)` sets the dog for myEntity as well...

Comment: May I ask what do you think my question is ? Cause I had a lot of (now deleted) answers and I find it funny that most of them were totally way off. :p I must have expressed myself so badly

Comment: I believe it's mostly about not forgetting to call a setter when you have a dozen of them to call. And about avoiding all that typing. My answer may help with not forgetting, but not with typing.